# How to pass array index value in string using php?

Tags: php

I want to write and pass array index value in string to another php file. Kindly check what I am doing:

```
<?php
$pages = array("Story1","Story2","Story3");
$fp = fopen('urls.php', 'w');
for($i=0;$i<$length;$i++){
fwrite($fp, '<a href="kids-{$pages[$i]}">Kids App Stories</a><br>');
}
fclose($fp);
?>
```

I am having problem below line:

```
fwrite($fp, '<a href="kids-{$pages[$i]}">Kids Stories</a><br>');
```

The above line write as it is in urls.php

```
<a href="kids-**{$pages[$i]}**">Kids Stories</a><br>
<a href="kids-**{$pages[$i]}**">Kids Stories</a><br>
<a href="kids-**{$pages[$i]}**">Kids Stories</a><br>
```

While I am expecting the output:

```
<a href="kids-story1">Kids Stories</a><br>
<a href="kids-story2">Kids Stories</a><br>
<a href="kids-story3">Kids Stories</a><br>
```

I want in urls story1,story2,story3 instead of {$pages[$i]}

Any idea or suggestions would be welcome.

Comment: Put the value in your `fwrite()` call in double quotes as single quotes does as your seeing(not interpreting substitutions)

Comment: `fwrite($fp, "<a href=\"kids-{$pages[$i]}\">Kids Stories</a><br>");`

Comment: Why not simply do it like this. `fwrite($fp, '<a href="kids-'.$pages[$i].'">Kids Stories</a><br>');`